# Why does the Hyper Accelerated Dragon avoid the Rossolimo?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense

After
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 g6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nc6

Why is the Rossolimo line impossible for white?

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 g6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nc6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Rossolimo proper,

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "Rossolimo variation"]
[Startply "5"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 g6
```

white usually holds back pawn to `d4` and doubles black pawns with `Bxc6`, or later builds a center with an eventual `c3` followed by `d4`.

In the Open Sicilian,

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "Open Sicilian"]
[Startply "9"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 g6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nc6 5. Bb5?!
```

none of these plans are available, and `5. Bb5` doesn't make much sense. Besides, the bishop on `b5` is tactically vulnerable to a later black `Qa5+` or `Qb6`.

Comment: I would just like to add, in response to the phrasing of the original question, that it is not "impossible" to transpose to the Rossolimo by playing 5.Bb5 (it's as if you started the Rossolimo and then played 4.d4 cxd4 5.Nxd4), and it's not even terrible; it's just not very good.